# Managing Daylight Standard Time vs Daylight Savings Time for limiting access to an application

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a solution currently managing login/logout times for an application. We have locations in CST and EST that operate in their respective timezones.

The desired login/logout time is being captured as a pattern which displayed below, and is then being localized to the users time zone. This works well until we cross the line for daylight savings/standard time.

Example data in the table below. All are DATETIME2.

| ID | LoginStartTimeUTC | WorkStartTimeUTC | WorkEndTimeUTC | LoginEndTimeUTC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0001-01-01 13:00:00.0000000 | 0001-01-01 13:00:00.0000000 | 0001-01-01 22:00:00.0000000 | 0001-01-02 04:59:00.0000000 |

To change this to local time, we are calculating the number of minutes to the start of todays date and then adding those to the values in the table above.

```
DECLARE 
    @MinutesToToday BIGINT = 1064095200, --Number of minutes to start of today UTC
    @MinutesToYesterday BIGINT = 1064093760; --Number of minutes to start of yesterday UTC

        SELECT 
             ID
            ,DATEADD(MINUTE, @MinutesToToday, LoginStartTimeUTC) AS TodaysLoginStartTimeUTC
            ,DATEADD(Minute, @MinutesToToday, LoginEndTimeUTC) AS TodaysLoginEndTimeUTC
            ,DATEADD(Minute, @MinutesToToday, WorkStartTimeUTC) AS TodaysWorkStartTimeUTC
            ,DATEADD(Minute, @MinutesToToday, WorkEndTimeUTC) AS TodaysWorkEndTimeUTC
,CAST(CASE WHEN GETUTCDATE() BETWEEN TodaysWorkStartTimeUTC AND TodaysWorkEndTimeUTC THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS CurrentlyInsideWorkHours
        ,CAST(CASE WHEN GETUTCDATE() BETWEEN TodaysLoginStartTimeUTC AND TodaysLoginEndTimeUTC THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS CurrentlyInsideLoginHours
        FROM HoursOfBusiness
```

| TodaysLoginStartTimeUTC | TodaysLoginEndTimeUTC | TodaysWorkStartTimeUTC | TodaysWorkEndTimeUTC | CurrentlyInsideWorkHours | CurrentlyInsideLoginHours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-11 13:00:00.0000000 | 2024-03-11 22:00:00.0000000 | 2024-03-11 13:00:00.0000000 | 2024-03-11 22:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 1 |

The output is correct and this works as expected until time changes. Then, my login times are either shifted an hour based on the time change because 8am EST moves from 13:00 UTC to 12:00 UTC.

This morning, users would have been unable to log in until 9am EST which is equal to 8 AM EDT.

My plan is this:

1. Capture a timestamp on the row each time an edit is made (LastEditDateTimeUTC)
2. When localizing time... compare timestamp to see if the record was entered during standard or savings time. Check the current date to see if it is currently savings or standard time. If XOR then make adjustment +/- an hour where needed.

My question is this: Is there a better way to manage conversion to/from local time when dealing with daylight savings time than what I am proposing above with the goal of returning the correct UTC value accounting for our business hours whether in EDT or EST.

Comment: Are you just converting from utc to local time? Would you provide some sample results, please? It would help clarify your question.

Comment: I'll update above momentarily.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something but why not use AT TIMEZONE to convert to localtime?

Comment: AT TIME ZONE will return the correct local time, however our business hours are not adjusted with the change from EDT and EST. The below will return me 8am on 3/9 and 9am on 3/11 when my business hours remain 8am both days. 
`Declare @preDST DATETIME2 = '2024-03-09 13:00:00', @postDST DATETIME2 = '2024-03-11 13:00:00';

SELECT @preDST AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'EASTERN STANDARD TIME', @postDST AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'EASTERN STANDARD TIME';`

Comment: I could use a Time(7) field instead, however then I run into the issue of having some shifts run over night and now my start times are after my end times.

Comment: You want to localize the timestamp, but remove daylight savings?

Comment: [You've given us mostly technical details about your solution. It would help us if you talked about the business problem you're trying to solve.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: We use a 3rd part tool called TimeZoneSource. It comes with an XML file we can modify for custom DST/ST handling. We use it to handle conversion of or database server times in NewYork (GMT -05:00) to local client times and vice versa.